# Title with javascript and slice property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on a project with a Radio Api that we made. I was working with javascript and I wanted to create a fadeout title that makes the last 2 letters of a song fade out. I ended up with something like:

```
let srt =  document.getElementById('songTitle');
if(srt.length > 20)
{
 let sliced = srt.slice(-2);
 sliced.style.opacity = '1';
}
```

This code didn't work at all, so I tried another approach to the code and made a css style with the classname of ".FadeOut".
Then changed the javascript with:

```
let srt =  document.getElementById('songTitle');
if(srt.length > 20)
{
 let sliced = srt.slice(-2);
 sliced.classList.add(".FadeOut");
}
```

Still, the code is not working. Then I tried to see if in the console.log the slicing of the last 2 letters was doing it right, and yes, the console gives me the last 2 letters of the title I'm working on...
Any suggest would be great!!
Thanks!

Comment: Opacity 1 is the default. It won't change anything. You want opacity of 0.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

Comment: @ddastrodd this is the error that I have when I use the opacity, even if it is 0 or 1 "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'opacity')"

Answer (score 0):

Your `srt` is an HTMLElement - not a string. An element doesn't have a `.length` property (and you can't `.slice` it), nor does assigning to the style of a sliced string make sense - you can only change the style of *elements*.

For this to work, change the HTML so that the last two characters of the title are in their own `<span>`, then change the style of that element.

```js
const songTitleDiv = document.querySelector('#songTitle');
if (songTitleDiv.textContent.length > 20) {
  const lastTwoCharactersSpan = songTitleDiv.children[0];
  lastTwoCharactersSpan.style.opacity = '0';
  // or toggle the classList
}
```

```html
<div id="songTitle">Some Very Very Long Song Tit<span>le</span></div>
```

If the `songTitle` is populated dynamically, you can slice the last two characters of the string when inserting it as HTML and surround them in the `<span>`.

```js
const songTitleDiv = document.querySelector('#songTitle');
const songTitle = 'Some Very Very Long Song Title';
const [startingTitle, lastTwoCharacters] = songTitle.split(/(?=..$)/);
// Insert song title with a <span> around the last two characters
songTitleDiv.textContent = startingTitle;
songTitleDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('span')).textContent = lastTwoCharacters;

// Then, when desired, hide the last two characters if the title is long
setTimeout(() => {
  if (songTitleDiv.textContent.length > 20) {
    const lastTwoCharactersSpan = songTitleDiv.children[0];
    lastTwoCharactersSpan.style.opacity = '0';
    // or toggle the classList
  }
}, 3000);
```

```html
<div id="songTitle"></div>
```

Comment: That's nice but what's that "(/(?=..$)/)"?

Comment: That's a regular expression. It splits a string into two parts: what comes first, followed by the two characters that come at the end. `(?=` is lookahead, `..` matches two of any character, and `$` matches the end of the string. If you don't like it you can use a few `.slice`s instead.

Comment: That's great! But If I wanted to make everything after that 20 character disappear? Not by choosing how many characters needs to disappar but it does it automatically when going past that 20 characters of starting title

Comment: Then use `songTitle.slice(0, 20)` to get the first portion and `songTitle.slice(20)` to get the second. Or, if you don't want to display the second portion at all, ever, you can just use the first portion, insert it as the new `.textContent`, and drop the `<span>` and styling entirely.